# стили миниатюры в wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

немогу поставить точно такой же класс как на простых фотках
вот вывод миниатюры

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { 
    $large_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
    echo '<a href="' . $large_image[0] . '">'  . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail') . '</a>';
}
?>
```

а вот фотки с товара

```
                                <?php
    sb_get_images_for_product(wpsc_the_product_id()); ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wpsc_the_product_permalink() ); ?>">
                                    <img class="no-image" id="product_image_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>" alt="No Image" title="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo WPSC_CORE_THEME_URL; ?>wpsc-images/noimage.png" width="<?php echo get_option('product_image_width'); ?>" height="<?php echo get_option('product_image_height'); ?>" />
                                    </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
```

пробовал class="thickbox" поставить но неполучается

1. покапался в functions

   вот код поменял

   ```
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { /
           $large_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
           echo '<a rel="lightbox[<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>]" href="<?php echo $full_image_attributes[0]; ?>" class="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_image_link_classes(); ?>">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail') . '</a>';
       }
   ```

?>

Но походу как то неправильно я пишу чтоли через firebug показывает так

```
 rel="lightbox[&lt;?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?&gt;]» href=»&lt;?php echo $full_image_attributes[0]; ?&gt;» class=»&lt;?php echo wpsc_the_product_image_link_classes(); ?&gt;«&gt;&lt;img width="></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

```
 <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { /
    $large_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
    echo '<a rel="lightbox[<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>]" href="'. $full_image_attributes[0] .'" class="'/ wpsc_the_product_image_link_classes(). '>">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail') . '</a>';
}
```

Вы при открытом тэге php попытались открыть его ещё раз